# Web Scraping - Although tag is shown during inspection can't find it while scraping using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Nowadays, Amazon is not showing prices on the category page for many categories when one is trying to scrape from a different location(country). In fact, it is not showing pricing in the product page as well. Only when the user clicks on "See all buying options" do they get to see the pricing of the product. On inspection that price is under the span of class a-offscreen but using BeautifulSoup that tag is returning empty values. Why is this happening and what is the solution/effective way to get these prices?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(required Amazon product url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
prices = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'a-offscreen'})
```

But **prices** does not contain the required information. It contains data from other a-offscreen classes but not the prices which we get to see by clicking on "See all buying options".

This is the main function which runs for the particular search term and scrapes effectively. get_url is the function that generates the particular url for the search term and extract_record is the function that contains the code for extraction.
Note - I am extracting for multiple pages for particular search terms as evident from the code. Where do I fit in the code to change the zip code here?

```
def main(search_term):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    records=[]
    url=get_url(search_term)

    for page in range(1,10):
        driver.get(url.format(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
        results = soup.find_all('div',{'data-component-type':'s-search-result'})
    
       for item in results:
           record = extract_record(item)
           if record:
               records.append(record)
                           
    driver.close()

    with open('csv.csv','w',newline='',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer=csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'])
        writer.writerows(records)
```

Please overlook Indentation error if any.

[This confirm button needs to be pressed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjXgC.png)

So far I have added another line to get_zip(driver) function but it's not working-

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="GLUXConfirmClose"]').click()`

**Please enter valid zip code problem**

[Please enter valid zip code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNsIg.png)

Comment: Because this data would be loaded dynamically after the button is clicked, so the data is not there at all

Comment: Yes, but on inspection it does exist and even when the tab is not open the data is present in the a-offscreen tag

Answer (score 0):

To get the **prices** specifically of the different products, this could help you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/Amazing-Spider-Man-Omnibus-Vol/dp/130290082X") # example url
try:

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buybox-see-all-buying-choices"]/span/a').click()

    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
            (By.ID, 'all-offers-display-scroller'))
   )
except:
    driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
prices = [elem.text for elem in soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'a-offscreen'}) if "$" in 
elem.text]
print(prices)
```

Click the "See all buying options" button, wait for the display scroller to be located, and scrape all the elements with the class a-offscreen from the page source.

Here's how you would change the zip code. In this example, it will show results for Portland (zip code 97217). Unless you close the driver or stop your program, you should only need to enter the zip code once, so I would do it before scraping anything.

**Update: I added some delays, tell me if this works. If not, it might be because the xpaths in my code are referencing the wrong elements for the page you are trying to scrape. I am only confident that this works on the amazon.com homepage**

**Update 2: You said that there's an error with my get_zip() function not clicking a "confirm" button**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def get_zip(driver):
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-global-location-popover-link"]')
    )).click()

    zipcode_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GLUXZipUpdateInput"]')
    ))

    zipcode_e.click()
    zipcode_e.send_keys('97217')  # <- example zip code
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GLUXZipUpdate"]/span/input')
    )).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="a-popover-3"]/div/div[2]/span/span')
    )).click()
```

## Basic functionality

**I added a function to clear cookies. I also updated get_zip function**

```
# skipped imports

def get_zip(driver):
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-global-location-popover-link"]')
    )).click()

    zipcode_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GLUXZipUpdateInput"]')
    ))

    zipcode_e.click()
    zipcode_e.send_keys('97217')  # <- example zip code
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="GLUXZipUpdate"]/span/input')
    )).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="a-popover-3"]/div/div[2]/span/span')
    )).click()


def main(search_term):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.delete_all_cookies()  # clear all cookies
    get_zip(driver)
    records = []
    url = get_url(search_term)
    for page in range(1, 10):
        driver.get(url.format(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        results = soup.find_all('div', {'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})

        for item in results:
            record = extract_record(item)
            if record:
                records.append(record)

    driver.close()

    with open('csv.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
        writer.writerows(records)
main("shampoo")
```

Tell me in the comments if you require anything further, or if something doesn't work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230312/discussion-on-answer-by-twiddler-web-scraping-although-tag-is-shown-during-ins).